# Pegar a porta do IP em uma string

Tags: php

To com um problema aqui, eu preciso separar uma string de IP em duas partes, entre o endereço e a porta.

Exemplo:

```
$string = 127.0.0.1:7777;
$string = px01.carbonhost.com.br:7786
```

Virar:

```
$string1 = 127.0.0.1;
$string2 = 7777;

$string1 = px01.carbonhost.com.br;
$string2 = 7786;
```

Assim seria o jeito mais fácil pra mim, a outra solução seria eu fazer o usuário  colocar o IP e a Porta separadamente, o problema é que muitos já cadastraram o IP junto com a porta.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: se o problema é ter no DB cadastrado junto e você for separar na aplicação, compensa separar via SQL em 2 campos (direto no DB)

Answer (score 7):

Pode usar o [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.parse-url.php):

*Exemplo:*

```
<?php   

    $array_info1 = (parse_url("127.0.0.1:7777"));
    $array_info2 = (parse_url("px01.carbonhost.com.br:7786"));
```

*Saída*

```
array(2) { ["host"]=> string(9) "127.0.0.1" ["port"]=> int(7777) } 

array(2) { ["host"]=> string(22) "px01.carbonhost.com.br" ["port"]=> int(7786) }
```

*Modo de Usar*

```
echo $array_info1['host'];  
echo $array_info1['port'];
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar a função explode do PHP.

Essa função funciona basicamente desta maneira: você dá como *input* um delimitador/separador e uma *string*. A função pegará a *string* que você forneceu e a partirá em cada nó (abalizações), formando um *array* de tamanho `n + 1`, onde `n` é o número de vezes que o delimitador foi encontrado na *string* passada.

Para acessar os valores do *array*, deve-se usar os índices de cada elemento formado pela quebra da *string* (o número de elementos no *array* será igual ao número de vezes que o demarcador for encontrado):

```html
<?php

$input = '127.0.0.1:7777';

$ip = explode(':', $input);

$num_ip = $ip[0];
$porta = $ip[1];

echo 'Número IP: ' . $num_ip . '<br>' . 'Porta: ' . $porta;
```

---

**Referências:**

> explode: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php